# Would keeping all punctuation make any sense in word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I am trying to learn how word2vec works to get to more complicated stuff like LSTMs. 
Because I will use the same training data (so with the same vocabulary) and I want to predict punctuation too, I decided to keep it.

Punctuation is obviously limited to `.!,?`, anything else is discarded (The sentence itself to avoid loss of meaning). Also, every symbol is converted into a string-like representation to avoid any kind of problems with encoding.

Now, does it make sense to keep punctuation? Should I discard it completely (if I do discard it, how can I generate punctuation for seq2seq model later?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to keep punctuation if you want to be able to predict it.

Tokenization of your input should actually work for any character, be it a letter or punctation. In fact there have already been exmaples of people modelling mathematics using Word2Vec and then generating very realistic maths, via $\LaTeX$ !  Look at the subsection called Algebraic Geometry in [Karpathy's now famous blog post](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/).

There is a good [note on the matter here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290238/how-to-deal-with-punctuations-in-machine-translation), whcih a specific example given in seq2seq learning (basically translation within the realm of NLP). Be sure to read the comments on the accepted answer there.

to answer your final question, I don't think it would be possible to use your generated model to place to required punctuation back into your model, as something like an LSTM would not have a representation for, say a comma, as it had never seen one.